# Javascript button click event is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Hi i have below fiddle which is working fine!!

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7ch893c/1/)

But i have copied same in below fiddle. But it is not working. I am really worried about this doubt. Please help me by explain this. Then only i can sleep properly.

[Not Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skdxuwgr/)

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
```

Javascript

```
function change() {
  alert("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: `change` is not defined error

Comment: @PraneshRavi Have you seen working fiddle?? It is working... How it is?

Comment: Timing leads to diffrent scoping between fiddles, i.e. "No wrap in <head>" vs. "onLoad".

Comment: if you want to declare global function in `onLoad` event you could like this: `window.change = function(){ ... };`

Comment: @Teemu Can you please tell me, where is option to change the no wrap in head...

Comment: @Teemu Yes i find it, it is in the area of javascript..

Comment: @Teemu Really Thanks!!!! Great help.... I can sleep properly....

Answer (score 0):

This is because your javascript load type has been set to OnLoad
To resolve the issue,

1) Click on JavaScript settings button near to your function [right hand side of function]

2) Select mootools 1.4.5 version in framework and extension

3) This is important. In load type select No Wrap - In Head option

4) Click on run.

Now your function will work.

Why it is executing now because we had made the load type as No Wrap in Head and changed it from onLoad. Because of this your function is global now and it can be referenced. If it is OnLoad then it can be referenced within the function call only.

I Hope this helps. :)